# ¿Cómo cargo un vídeo que está en el disco fuera del localhost?

Tags: html5, web, video

Necesito acceder a una dirección que está en el disco duro, para darle esta url a un src de un elemento para colocar un vídeo, pero no puedo porque corro la página desde localhost, apache, y debe ser desde el computador de donde se cargue el vídeo.

¿Cómo lo hago?

```
<video height="385" width="640" src="C:\Users\leand\Videos\temp.mp4" controls autoplay id="video">HTML5 Video is required for this example</video>
```

¿Qué dirección pongo en src?

Comment: Si, entiendo, pero es que la idea es que es un reproductor de video, que toma los videos del usuario, el atributo src, se cambiaría desde jquery o javascript.

Comment: Desde apache no podrá acceder al disco local  obviamente, si desea acceder localmente debe ejecutar su archivo html fuera del servidor.

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien, eso que pides no se puede hacer. Ten en cuenta que el contenido que se muestra en un navegador se reproduce desde el navegador y es el cliente el que tiene que tener acceso a ese recurso. Si quieres que el navegador acceda a un recurso al que no tiene acceso... no vas a poder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haciéndo exégesis de la pregunta, todos han inferido que el OP quiere mostrar en su sitio web un archivo que está en su servidor, sólo que está fuera del `document_root`. Sin embargo, hay una interpretación alternativa:

> debe ser desde el computador de donde se cargue el vídeo.

Esto se puede entender como que el OP quiere reproducir desde el browser un video que está **en el disco local del visitante**.

Eso último **no** se puede hacer. Hay una limitación de seguridad férrea respecto a cargar desde un sitio web archivos locales del visitante.

Imagínate, si no, que yo pudiese hacer que todos los visitantes a mi sitio  vieran en un textarea su archivo de passwords. Para mí sería trivial hacer un autosubmit y guardar en mi backend datos privados del visitante.

Comment: Exacto, ud si me entendió, ya entendí que no se puede, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando un servidor `apache`, en principio no puedes cargar vídeos desde fuera de la carpeta web. Debes colocar todos los archivos dentro del directorio web usado por tu servidor (por defecto la carpeta `htdocs`). Para acceder a éstos archivos desde `localhost` (asumiendo que tu servidor esté conectado por `localhost`), utiliza el nombre de dominio `localhost` o la dirección `IP 127.0.0.1`.

No obstante, lo más recomendable es usar **rutas relativas** y no absolutas. Por ejemplo, si creo una carpeta `Videos` dentro de `htdocs` y subo el archivo `mp4` a dicha carpeta, asumiendo que el archivo `html` se encuentre en la raíz del directorio web, en `src` escribiría:

`src="Videos/temp.mp4"`

Si tuviera que escribir la ruta absoluta, sería:

`src="http://localhost/Videos/temp.mp4"`

o

`src="http://127.0.0.1/Videos/temp.mp4"`

Comment: Rutas relativas vs absolutas... sobre que es recomendable, es algo bastante personal y no general. En los casos que expones, por ejemplo faltó: `src="/Videos/temp.mp4"` que puede ser una opción adicional si desea después cambiarlo a un servidor de producción. Mantiene _la ruta absoluta_ sin necesidad de cambiar todas las `url`. Y es válido para `http://localhost/Videos/temp.mp4`, `http://127.0.0.1/Videos/temp.mp4`, `http://www.midominio.com/Videos/temp.mp4`...

Answer (score 0):

Buenas creo que tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta. Pero el video no debes de colocarlo en esa carpeta. EL video lo tendrás que colocar en la carpeta de `localhost` que es la siguiente:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs
```

Yo utilizao `XAMPP`, pues dentro de esa carpeta de `htdocs`, si quieres creas una carpeta llamada `videos`.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<video height="385" width="640" src="http://localhost/videos/temp.mp4" controls autoplay id="video">HTML5 Video is required for this example</video>
```

Si lo que pides es fuera de `localhost` no se puede. Pero esto te serviría para tener el video en disco duro pero dentro de la carpeta de `localhost XAMPP`